Max distance in 2d and 3d positively curved space
On a 2d positively curved space (surface of a sphere), using polar coordinates, we have $ds^2 = dr^2 + R^2 sin^2(r/R) d\theta^2$. I understand we can calculate circumference by going around $\theta$ from 0 to 2$\pi$ and get a finite value. But if we were to fix $\theta$, and go along the $r$ direction, how do we show mathematically (i.e. bound of the integral, not intuitively) that the maximum distance along $r$ is finite?
Then, in a 3d positively curved space, $ds^2 = dr^2 + R^2 \sin^2(r/R)[d\theta + \sin^2\theta d^2\phi]$, and the circumference calculated going around $\theta$ is $2\pi$R $\sin(r/R)$. Here we say even if $r$ goes to infinity, the circumference is still finite. But what if I just pick a geodesic along $r$ ($\theta$ and $\phi$ being held fixed), and keep going? I'll never come back to the same point am I because $r$ can be infinity? But isn't positively curved 3d space supposed to be finite?

How can you move along the $r$ direction on the surface of a sphere?

You are confusing the concepts of path length and shortest distance. It does not help that the unqualified term distance may refer to either concept, depending on context.
If (for a given metric) you take the line element $ds$ and integrate it along a path $P$ from point $A$ to point $B$ the result is the path length from $A$ to $B$. The path length $l(A,B,P)$ obviously depends on the path $P$, and not just on the end points $A$ and $B$. By choosing a suitably convoluted and indirect path we can make the path length $l(A,B,P)$ between any two points as large as we like. We could even make $l(A,B,P)$ as large as we like by choosing a path $P$ that goes from $A$ to $B$, then back to $A$, then back to $B$ again, as many times as we like - there is nothing that says that points along a path may only be visited once.
However, we cannot make the path length between $A$ and $B$ as small as we like. Out of all the possible paths from $A$ to $B$ there will be some path  (or maybe a set of such paths) for which $l(A,B,P)$ has a minimum value. This value is the shortest distance $d(A,B)$ between $A$ and $B$, and the paths $P$ for which $l(A,B,P) = d(A,B)$ are called geodesics.
We can define metric spaces (and the surface of a sphere is one example) in which the shortest distance $d(A,B)$ between any two points in the space is always less than some maximum value, no matter how we choose $A$ and $B$. We call this a bounded space. However, even in a bounded space, we can still create paths that have a path length as long as we like - the path length $l(A,B,P)$ between two points $A$ and $B$ can take any value as long as $l(A,B,P) \ge d(A,B)$.
So if you start off at any point $A$ on the surface of a sphere and follow a great circle path (which is what I think you mean by constant $\theta$) you will eventually reach the antipodal point $A'$, and if you continue you will come back to $A$. The path length (which you find by integrating $ds$ along the path) increases all the way from $A$ to $A'$ and continues to increase as you return to $A$ - and you could create a path as long as you like by following the great circle back to $A'$, then back to $A$ again and so on.
However, the shortest distance $d(A,B)$ between $A$ and a point $B$ on this path (or on any other path that starts from $A$) is limited to a maximum value because the surface of a sphere (using the standard metric) is a bounded space. $d(A,B)$ increases as $B$ moves from $A$ to $A'$, but then decreases again as $B$ moves from $A'$ back to $A$, until it becomes zero when $B$ gets back to $A$ - even though the path length $l(A,B,P)$ is not zero.

Yes, that's what I meant --- how do we mathematically prove "the shortest distance (,) between  and a point  on this path is limited to a maximum value because the surface of a sphere (using the standard metric) is a bounded space" IF we choose a path that goes along "r" instead of $\theta$.  In theta we know we integrate from 0 to 2$\pi$ and it's finite, what I'm questioning is how do we justify that for r the upper bound is 2$\pi$R, without using the result from the $\theta$ integral or the visual knowledge that it's a sphere.

Your answer though cleared my confusion on the 3d case. Thank you. The 2d case please see the other comment.

@ABC On the surface of a sphere the path with shortest length between two points A and B lies along an arc of a great circle. And the maximum length of the great circle arc is $\pi R$ (not $2 \pi R$) and this occurs when A and B are antipodal points. If A and B are not antipodal points then $d(A,B) < \pi R$ because you take the length of the shorter great circle arc connecting A and B, not the longer arc.

@ABC In the general case, if you don't know you are on the surface of a sphere, or you have a more complicated surface then it is going to be difficult to find geodesics (paths of shortest length) or prove whether or not the surface is bounded - you would have to use differential geometry and do a lot of surveying.

@ABC Although in physics the problem of finding geodesics in spacetime is solved for us because we know that light (in a vacuum)  always travels along a geodesic.


How do we show that the maximum distance along ( r ) is finite?

In a 2-sphere, when you move along $r$, you will eventually return to your starting point after traveling a distance of $2\pi R$. You can visualize this as moving along the surface of the Earth in a straight line. While it may seem like you are always moving forward and away from where you started, you will eventually return to the same point.

Will I never come back to the same point because ( r ) can be infinite?

The range of $r$ is not infinite also in 3-sphere. Similarly, in a 3-sphere, when you move along $r$, you will return to the same point after traveling a distance equal to the circumference of the 3-sphere. Visually, it may seem like you won't return, but eventually, you'll come back to the same place.

@safesphere in 2-sphere $r$ is not the radius of the sphere...Radius is the $R$

Ah, I see. Sorry, I was half asleep :) I’ve deleted my comments and +1 to cancel someone’s unjustified downvote. And also thanks for GRPy, I’ll check it out.

@safesphere thanks :)
